# Expected winnings in a game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I pay 3 pence to play a game. I roll two unbiased die and compare the score to 8. I win a number of pence according to the the difference between my scores and 8. 
What is the expected winnings per game?

I have defined my discrete random variable $Y = X-8$ , where X is the score I get from two dice.
Then I am getting the pdf for Y but I can not figure out the probabilities of Y. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of winnings per game in which you pay $3$ pence per game and win the difference between the number you roll on your pair of dice, $X$, and the number $8$ can be represented as the following random variable:

$$ Y = \left|X - 8 \right| - 3 $$

That is, the amount of winnings based on the roll minus the buy-in of $3$ pence.

The expected winnings per game follows from the definition of expectation:

\begin{align*}
E[Y] = \sum_x y(x)p(x)
\end{align*}

Where $y(x)$ is the value of $Y$ at $X = x$, and $p(x)$ is the probability of $X = x$.  Thus, you can compute your expected winnings by taking the sum of the product of $Y$ and the probability of $X$ at each possible outcome of your rolls ($X = 2$ through $X = 12$ for six-sided dice).

**For example:**

At $X = 2$,  you have $y(2) = \left|1 - 8\right| - 3 = 4$ and $p(2) = \frac{1}{36}$, because there is one possible way to roll a $2$ out of $36$ possible rolls (assuming six-sided dice).  So $y(2)p(2) = \frac{4}{36} = \frac{1}{9}$.  You need to compute this product for all possible values of $X$ and take their sum.

Comment: Got it! My answer is - 8/9p as expected!

Comment: Glad to help.  Feel free to accept this answer if it satisfied your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your definition of $Y$ is correct,

You will find that the frequency of occurrence of sums of $2-12$ follows the pattern $1-2-3-4-5-6-5-4-3-2-1$

so Expected earnings $= \dfrac {-(6\cdot1 +5\cdot2 +4\cdot3 + 3\cdot4 +2\cdot5 + 1\cdot6) + (0\cdot5 +1\cdot4 + 2\cdot3 + 3\cdot2 + 4\cdot1)}{36} - 3 $

Which fool will play such a game ?

And if $Y = |X-8|$, which fool will offer such money ?